# USB Flash Drive is not recognised on Android phone

Tags: bluetooth, usb-on-the-go

I bought the Wansenda S100 OTG USB Flash Drive 32GB USB 2.0 For Android Devices/PC/Tablet/Mac with the intention to load MP3 music on it and play it on my android phone.

When I insert the flash drive into my phone, the phone doesn't seem to recognise it.

What I would like is for the phone to auto recognise and load the content of the flash drive so that I can select the songs I would like to play. The music will be played via bluetooth on a megaboom speaker.

Can anyone advise me how to make this happen?

Thank You!

Comment: Are you sure you phone is OTG ready?

Comment: What Android device do you have?

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure of the following things:**

- Phone is OTG ready and compatible (Not all phones support OTG connectivity).
- Flash Drive is correctly formatted (The storage device needs to be formatted as exFAT,FAT32 or something similar.).

If your phone is OTG compatible and flash drive is formatted correctly but it still doesn't work, then your flash drive might have some partitioning problems or it is just broken and will need to be replaced.